# 'URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. How to solve?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

When i hit the url https://www.instagram.com/mamunur105/?__a=1 . I get Some json data. But when i want those data by ajax. I get the error. How to solve this.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.instagram.com/mamunur105/?__a=1' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Ajax Code:

```
    (function($) {
        jQuery('body').on('click','.btn-lode',function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            // console.log(fd);
            var data = {};
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'https://www.instagram.com/mamunur105/?__a=1',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {},
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error Loading Data...");
                },
                complete: function() {
                }
            });
        });
  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
```

Please write this in the code block of ajax. That page is wanting headers.

Comment: Still not working. Can you check and provide here  working code ?

Comment: I can't test, you should send other codes too. As i learned, you should add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' in headers block. Can u try again?

Comment: Still same:   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'https://www.instagram.com/mamunur105/?__a=1',
      data: data,
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
      },
      beforeSend: function() {},
      success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(){
       alert("Error Loading Data...");
      },
      complete: function() {
      }
     });